# What does "rushy bed" mean in this context?

Tags: poetry, meaning, persian-language, rumi

The poem 'The Song of the Reed' by [Rumi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rumi) includes the lines:

> Hearken to this Reed forlorn,
>   Breathing, even since 'twas torn
>   From its rushy bed, a strain
>   Of impassioned love and pain.

(From *Rumi, Poet and Mystic 1207–1273*, translated by Reynold A. Nicholson.)

What is meant by "rushy bed"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Reeds (typha, or reedmace) and rushes (bulrush) are often confused, although they belong to different botanical families. In particular, typha (reedmace) is often misnamed as bulrush. Since both plants grow in water, you will often see them intermixed in streams and along riverbanks. So, a "rushy bed" is simply a bed of bulrushes (or typha).

Note also that a *reed* is a rustic musical instrument. So the *reed* in the poem would be made from the stem of a bulrush (or more properly, reedmace or typha), taken from its *rushy bed*.

[image: Typha, or reedmace (reedmace)]
[Typha, or reedmace (Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typha)

[image: Bulrush]
[Bulrush (Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bulrush)

> Reed (noun)
>
> 1.4 (literary) a rustic musical pipe made from a reed or from straw.
> ‘as if thy waves had only heard the shepherd's reed’

Oxford Online Dictionary

Comment: TL;DR: rushes ~ reeds. That seems to be what the OP wasn't realising.

Comment: @Randal'Thor Old habits. Saying that rushes is another name for reeds wouldn't cut it on some forums. They demand proof. :(